# GIPHY API returns the same results everytime

Tags: javascript, vue.js, giphy, giphy-api

I have this problem that the GIPHY API always returns the same results. And I'm quite sure this is not because I somehow store the previous result and post it again and again. For example, I type in 'dog' and ask for 5 results .. I get 5 dog gifs, then I refresh the page and repeat the process and get exactly the same gifs.

Is there an elegant solution to get random gifs every time I make a request?

The solution I thought of is: when I make a repeated request, I would request (under the hood) for 10 gifs and then would post on the page from these new 10 gifs just the 5 new ones but this solution can get quite messy when the amount of gifs needed will get larger.

Here's my code so far:

```
    <v-container>
        <v-layout text-center wrap>
            <v-flex xs12>
                <v-img :src="require('../assets/logo.svg')" class="my-3" contain height="200"></v-img>
            </v-flex>
            <v-text-field label="Search" outlined rounded v-model="searchText"></v-text-field>
            <v-btn outlined rounded block @click="findGIF">Search</v-btn>
            <div class="gifs" v-show="showGIFs" ref="gifs">
                <div v-for="(gif, index) in gifs" :key="index">
                    <img class="gif" :src="gif.preview" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            searchText: "",
            gifs: [],
            index: 1,
            showGIFs: true
        };
    },
    methods: {
        async fetchGIFs(number) {
            let apiKey = "myKey"; // deleted to keep it private
            let searchEndPoint = "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?";
            let limit = number;
            let gifsArray = [];

            let url = `${searchEndPoint}&api_key=${apiKey}&q=${this.searchText}&limit=${limit}`;

            try {
                let response = await fetch(url);
                let json = await response.json();

                json.data.forEach(gif => {
                    gifsArray.push({
                        url: gif.url,
                        preview: gif.images.preview_gif.url,
                        src: gif.images.original.url,
                        height: gif.images.original.height,
                        width: gif.images.original.width
                    });
                });

                return gifsArray;
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Ooops, take a look at this error: " + error);
            }
            return "I guess something didn't go right here";
        },

        findGIF() {
            let temp = [];
            (async () => {
                try {
                    temp = await this.fetchGIFs(5);
                    this.gifs.push(...temp);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log("Have a look at this: " + err);
                }
            })();
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GIPHY will return the same GIF object every time for the same query string using the Search Endpoint. If you want to randomize the results, that will be your job.

A possible solution is to create another array, extract random array entries from your `gifsArray` and push those entries to the new array and then return that array instead.

One alternative solution would be to use the Random Endpoint `api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/random`. This will work if you are fine with a single random GIF, as it returns a single random GIF.

Comment: Nice, thank you .. it helped.

While you are here .. do you have any idea how I could fist show a preview of the gif while the main one (which is quite big) is being downloaded .. and once the big gif is downloaded, how can I changed it in place of the preview? Is there a way to get notified  if a gif has been downloaded? Thank you.

Comment: I think your approach should rather be that you stick with only showing the preview of all the GIFs for a particular query and only request a higher quality version of the GIF once the user chooses a particular GIF. This is to save bandwidth. If you are going to request a large nr of GIFS, imagine the bandwidth load. 

I am not familiar with Vuetify (which I assume you use), but in standard HTML/JS you could, for eg, do

```previewGIFElem = document.getElementById(previewGIFId);
previewGifElem.onclick = function(e) {
//request larger GIF and fill that element with the larger GIF
};```